# How can I make a div element that will fill all remaining space and expand to the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css

1st of all, this is not exactly a footer. I don't want to use `position: fixed`. I have 2 different use cases. one, shown below, where the `Saved Quizzes` area should stick to the bottom of the page.`
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlxYy.png)

It is a direct child of `<body>`.

My other use case is here, where the grey area should extend to the bottom of the screen.
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7ZgO.png)

It's a child of a bunch of other elements. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Everything is procedurally generated HTML, using Kotlin-JS. The code for the first problem is as follows:

```
    val body = content.appendChild(document.createElement("div")) as HTMLDivElement
    body.className = "pad quizlist"
    body.id = "editor_qlist"
    val name = body.appendChild(document.createElement("h1")) as HTMLHeadingElement
    name.style.textAlign = "center"
    name.textContent = "Saved Quizzes"
    [...list all the questions...]
    [...Make the raw JSON input(not pictured)...]
    val add = body.appendChild(document.createElement("div")) as HTMLDivElement
    add.className = "add"
    add.onclick = {
        makeCreation(emptyList())
    }
    val h = add.appendChild(document.createElement("h1")) as HTMLHeadingElement
    h.textContent = "+"
    //TODO val spacer = body.appendChild(makeSpacer(body, true))
}
```

This code, with nothing in the list, and the JSON input removed comes out to this html:

```html
<div class="pad quizlist" id="editor_qlist">
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Saved Quizzes</h1>
    <div class="add">
        <h1>+</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the bits of CSS that actually matter:

```css
#editor_qlist {
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    padding: 2.5%;
}
div.quizlist {
    margin-top: 10%;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
div.pad {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 4mm;
    position: relative;
    left: 50%;
    width: 80%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
    padding: 1%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) as your question does not fit any of our guidelines

Comment: Can you show us your code so we can see what you have?

Comment: Just use position absolute then `bottom:0`

Comment: height + flex or grid, that's one of the easy things it brings, even display:table was efficient for this kind of things. show us your code and fails, so we can help not doing the coding for you ;) body is a direct child of HTML , it can be dealed like any other tag. body is not an issue , only a tag

Comment: @TamirKlein is this better?

Comment: @window.document that won't work. I need to be able to scroll through the list.